# Api is not calling on second click in IE11 in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm facing some weird issue in IE 11 only. In chrome it works very well but in IE api url is not calling on second click. I have listing page there are n numbers of records of ordered products. Then after clicking on each row will redirect to product detail page. In IE 11 I clicked first product it will show the data of clicked product if I go to the back and then select the another product and clicked the data of product not updating with clicked product it showing old product data. I checked the network tab where API url is not calling on second click. If I refresh the product data page the API will call and updated data will show. The API is calling in `componentDidMount` of pproduct data page. I'm just redirecting the page from product list to product data by using `this.context.router.history.push('/order-details?orderid=' + orderId);`

Even on second click orderID is changing with clicked product problem is only API url is not calling on click it will call after reload the page.

This is happening only in `IE 11` chrome, mozilla works well.

Below is my code.

Product data page which is calling in `componentDidMount`

```
  getPROrderData(this.props.userId, localStorage.companyGuid, localStorage.languageId, PRNumber, OrderID)
        .then((json) => {
            if (json.data.table1.length > 0) {
                alert(33)
                let priceDecimal = 0.0;
                //let grandFreightCost = 0.0;
                //alert(OrderID)
                this.setState({ orderData: json.data.table1 });
                json.data.table1.map(data => (
                    priceDecimal = priceDecimal + parseFloat(Number(Math.round(((data.quantity * data.unitPrice) + data.freightCost) + 'e2') + 'e-2').toFixed(decimalValue))
                    // priceDecimal = priceDecimal + parseFloat(Number(Math.round(((data.quantity * data.unitPrice) + data.freightCost) + 'e2') + 'e-2').toFixed(decimalPrecision()))
                ));
                // json.data.table1.map(data => (
                //     grandFreightCost = grandFreightCost + parseFloat(Number(Math.round(data.freightCost == null ? 0.0 : data.freightCode + 'e2') + 'e-2').toFixed(decimalPrecision()))
                // ));
                this.setState({ currencySymbol: json.data.table1[0].currencySymbol == null ? '$' : json.data.table1[0].currencySymbol })
                this.setState({ grandTotal: priceDecimal });
                // this.setState({ grandFreight: grandFreightCost });
            }
            if (json.data.table2.length > 0) {
                this.setState({ orderVariantAttributeData: json.data.table2 });
            }
            if (json.data.table3.length > 0) {
                this.setState({ orderArtworkData: json.data.table3 });
            }
            if (json.data.table4.length > 0) {
                this.setState({ orderStatus: json.data.table4 });
            }
            if (json.data.table5.length > 0) {
                this.setState({ orderComments: json.data.table5 });
            }
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Product lising page for redirecting to product data

```
 orderIDClickHandler = (orderId) => {
    this.context.router.history.push('/order-details?orderid=' + orderId);
}
```

Also `alert(33)` is calling on every product list click just api is not calling.

```
 <script src="//cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

is added to `index.html`

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: looking at the code it looks fine, just wanted to check whether the polyfill that you are including giving any polyfills back, can you just check that, or to be safe can you try including this "https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=es5,es6,es7&flags=always"

Comment: Could you please tell how to check that?

Comment: open http:////cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js in new tab and check

Comment: Yes its working..code is showing in IE developer tool in debugger tab

Comment: can you please use this, and check https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=es5,es6,es7&flags=always

Comment: can you please use this, and check https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=es5,es6,es7&flags=always

Comment: getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'distance' of undefined